# Docker Container termination on process termination

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want docker container stop or terminate itself if any process running inside docker container stops.

Any idea?

Comment: Stop the Docker container when a process crashes inside container

Comment: Basic to say, when main process crash, container exit. And `one process per container` is the best practice.